# CSS linear gradient breaks into horizontal rows

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

When trying to set a gradient background, instead of displaying a clean and linear gradient, the gradient kinda breaks into rows.
I've tried changing gradient generator, so the problem is not the generator, i've tried removing all the other css lines, the only thing that fixes the problem is removing the entire html content.
[Here is what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djMzC.png)
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flick.dev</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <h1 class="name">Flick.dev</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Home</a></li>
                <li><a>About</a></li>
                <li><a>Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn-contact">Contact</button>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <main>
        
    </main>

    <footer>

    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background: rgb(45,20,44);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(45,20,44,1) 0%, rgba(81,10,50,1) 25%, rgba(128,19,54,1) 50%, rgba(199,44,65,1) 75%, rgba(238,69,64,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(45,20,44,1) 0%, rgba(81,10,50,1) 25%, rgba(128,19,54,1) 50%, rgba(199,44,65,1) 75%, rgba(238,69,64,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(45,20,44,1) 0%, rgba(81,10,50,1) 25%, rgba(128,19,54,1) 50%, rgba(199,44,65,1) 75%, rgba(238,69,64,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#2d142c",endColorstr="#ee4540",GradientType=1);
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Sans;
    /* background-color: white; */
}
```

Comment: don't define fixed height on body, use min-height: 100% on html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thats because your `body` is not 100% of the screen height.
Put `height: 100vh` on the body.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background: rgb(45, 20, 44);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(45, 20, 44, 1) 0%, rgba(81, 10, 50, 1) 25%, rgba(128, 19, 54, 1) 50%, rgba(199, 44, 65, 1) 75%, rgba(238, 69, 64, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(45, 20, 44, 1) 0%, rgba(81, 10, 50, 1) 25%, rgba(128, 19, 54, 1) 50%, rgba(199, 44, 65, 1) 75%, rgba(238, 69, 64, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(45, 20, 44, 1) 0%, rgba(81, 10, 50, 1) 25%, rgba(128, 19, 54, 1) 50%, rgba(199, 44, 65, 1) 75%, rgba(238, 69, 64, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#2d142c", endColorstr="#ee4540", GradientType=1);
  height: 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Sans;
  /* background-color: white; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flick.dev</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <h1 class="name">Flick.dev</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button class="btn-contact">Contact</button>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <main>

  </main>

  <footer>

  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

Just add 100% to html tag

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

*If you add body height 100vh then it will not work when your page has more data and when you start scroll your page.